# Git : Switching between commits

Tags: git, repository

i have a question about GIT, i have a git repository like that:

```
(Commit0) - (Commit1) .... - (CommitN)
```

The problem is that a coworker wants to update his repository to (CommitN-10), how we can do that ?

Its posible to 1) put Master revision to (CommitN-10) 2) He update his revision 3) I can put back master to (CommitN)

Any ideas ?

PS. Sorry for my english

Comment: Which OS are you using? OF course it can be done. If you are using SourceTree, for example, you can pick the CommitN-10, and click on Checkout. Then, you will have all the changes until these commit. Hope it helps!

Comment: I am using Windows 8.1 with Git GUI

Comment: Update your question showing us the final state you want `master` to be on  your machine, your friend's machine, and the repo.

Comment: I want to put master revision to CommitN-10, then my coworker update his  repository and then i can put again master to CommitN. Is this possible with git reset soft ?

Comment: The safest way to do this is to have your friend pull the latest `master` and then do `git reset --hard HEAD~10` _from his own machine_.  I would recommend against pushing this out to the repo.

Comment: Ok, i will try this then TYVM

Answer (score 0):

If he just wants to get view the code at HEAD~10, do a `git checkout HEAD~10`. If he wants to start new work off that version, do a `git reset --HARD HEAD~10` and then he can do a `git checkout -b newBranchName` to start new work off that point on a new branch.

Comment: This sounds good, 1) git reset --HARD HEAD~10 2) git checkout -b newBranchName 3) git add + git commit + git push in order to put master branch again in CommitN .  ¿?